# Magento 2 Search within category product list

Tags: magento2.3, collection, catalog, layered-navigation

In magento 2, is it possible to have search option within category product listing?
please find below attach image
[image]

[updated]
finally, i have rewritten Listproduct.php class and search is working. The problem is layered navigation is not getting update based on search results.

```
        <?php

        namespace Mycomp\MyModule\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product;

        /**
         * Class ListProduct
         *
         * @package Mycomp\MyModule\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product
         */
        class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
        {

            protected function _getProductCollection()
            {
                $query = trim($this->getRequest()->getParam('query'));
                $this->_productCollection =  parent::_getProductCollection();
                if($query != ''){  return $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['like' => '%'.$query.'%']);}
                return $this->_productCollection; //->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['like' => '%ne%']);
            }

        }
```

Could you kindly help me?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()>addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer','LG')->load();
```

instead of manufacturer use your attribute and instead of LG use value on that attribute and whole productCollection will be filtered by that attribute value. 
so than you may use that products as you want. if any questions feel free to reply, I'll try to help.

Comment: i think we can't use 'addAttributeToSelect' to filter.  Above my code is working, The problem is layered navigation is not getting update based on search results, see highlighted section(count) in the attached image.  it was wrong.  (https://tinyurl.com/sjcroqm.